# Authentic text of Surya Siddhanta English Translation

Tags: surya, astronomy

Are there any authentic text of *Surya Siddhanta* English Translation? The following seem to be commonly available ones in Internet:

1. Surya - Siddhanta, By Ed. By S. Jain E. Burgees
2. The Surya-siddhanta
   and Siddhanta-siromani By Sri Danavir Goswami
3. Surya-Siddhanta: A Text Book of Hindu Astronomy, By Ebenezer Burgess (2007 Edition)
4. The Surya Siddhanta: A Text Book of Hindu Astronomy, By Phanindralal Gangooly,‎ Ebenzer Burgess (2000)

Comment: What do you mean by "authentic text"? Who is supposed to qualify any particular translation as "authentic"?

Answer (score 2):

Ignore Burgess, any other should be alright but not strictly accurate.

Note that its not just about the translation, it is about accurately interpreting the astronomical observations and information recorded in Surya Siddhanta.

There is a research paper published in a journal by retired ISRO scientist, Anil Narayanan in Indian Journal of History of Science about dating of Surya Siddhanta which is something you can start with.

There isn't much work done on Surya Siddhanta because 1.4 billion Indians are busy elsewhere.